# python comparing database results against strings

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to compare the output of a MSSQL (pyodbc) query against a seemingly similar tuple of strings, and python keeps telling me that they don't match.

```
def test_internship_direct_app_a_submit(self):

    address_result = SQLHelper.address_result("""
    select top 2 blah, blah, blah
            """ ) 
    print address_result[0]
    print type(address_result[0])
    print address_result[0] == ('1819 Harras Blvd', '', 'Atlantic City', 'NJ', '08401')
```

---

Console Output:
(u'1819 Harras Blvd', u'', u'Atlantic City', 'NJ', u'08401')

type 'pyodbc.Row'

False

---

**Question:** how can manipulate the output from the database in order for it to be easily compared to a list of strings in a tuple?  Thanks in advance

Oh, and here is the code in python I use to fetch the data:

```
def address_result(sql, param1):
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

params = (param1)
cursor.execute(sql ,params)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

addresses= []
for row in rows:
    addresses.append(row)


cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
return addresses
```

Comment: Try printing out what your database returned.  That might offer a clue.

Comment: If I type in those two tuples I get True as expected but 'pyodbc.Row' isn't a Tuple but it's `repr` looks like one. You'll need to convert it to a Tuple. On their site they say ``Note that slicing rows returns tuples, not Row objects!`` does that mean ``address_result[0][:]`` would be OK?

Comment: Are the string data types defining the MSSQL columns char fields or varchar? If the full number of characters isn't used up in char fields, then a bunch of spaces will be returned with the value. Ex: if the address column has a data type of char(20), then `1819 Harras Blvd` will actually be returned as `1819 Harras Blvd[space][space][space]   `.

Comment: I am doing a very similar thing but i am looking for the most effecient way as I have very large datasets, both db results and lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the objects being returned from the database are of type pyodbc.Row not real tuples.

Add this to the end of your test script and attain enlightenment:

```
print tuple(address_result[0]) == ('1819 Harras Blvd', '', 'Atlantic City', 'NJ', '08401')
```